# Enabling and disabling textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to VBA so I am sorry if this seems like a silly question.
I'm trying to have the TextBox next to the "Other date:" set so that you can only write in it if the "other date" button is selected.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdGkX.png]

so far this is what I have which obviously is not working :)

```
Private Sub otherDateTextBox_Change()

If Me.todayButton.Value = True Then
    Me.otherDateTextBox.Locked = True
ElseIf Me.tomorrowButton.Value = True Then
    Me.otherDateTextBox.Locked = True
ElseIf Me.otherDateButton.Value = True Then
    Me.otherDateTextBox.Locked = False

End If

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: for any clarification, this is how the Form looks like: https://imgur.com/a/eDhhbT2

Comment: Don't you only need to check if the other button is ticked? Why is it obvious that it is not working, and what exactly does that mean anyway? I think textboxes have an Enabled property.

Comment: Just `otherDateTextBox.Enabled = otherDateButton.Value` should work..

Comment: @RaymondWu I've tried that before as well and that doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: @elSwizzle Please elaborate how is it not working, statement such as `doesn't seem to be working`/`not working` is not helpful for debugging because it does not provide any detail. Have you step through the code and see if the event/line triggers? set a breakpoint and step through it if you haven't it.

Comment: Btw, you should put that line in `otherDateButton_Change` event and not in `otherDateTextBox_Change` event which is shown in your question.. @elSwizzle

Comment: omg yes you are right! thank you so much. now it works! sorry for the hick up! @RaymondWu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong event since the state of `otherDateTextBox` is determined by the value of `otherDateButton` so you should use the `Change` event of `otherDateButton`.

You can use the `Enabled` property to "lock" the text box so that it is not selectable and not editable (will show as grey out)

```
Private Sub otherDateButton_Change()
     otherDateTextBox.Enabled = otherDateButton.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: if your design for the 3 buttons is to have "only 1 selected among the 3" then you can add in lines to set the value of the other 2 buttons to `False`. Same logic goes to the other 2 buttons

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to disable the TextBox when the form is loaded/activated

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    TextBox1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

So it will be disabled by default. After that add the below code to enable the TextBox when Option1 is True or False.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        TextBox1.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Also you can clear out the text in TextBox before disabling it by

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()
    If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        TextBox1.Enabled = True
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```